# Getting 502 Bad gateway errors intermittently in Azure kubernetes(AKS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, microservices, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

we have recently shifted production instance of our app from VM into Kubernetes environment and very randomly at some times it's giving 502 bad gateway error. The app frontend runs on React and backend we are using 11-12 node js microservices. Only one microservice is giving this 502 error which is under more load compared to the other microservices. I have tried to check the kubernetes pod logs of that microservice but it doesn't give any helpful info as you can see

[image: here]

As some of articles on internet suggested there might be issue with new pods created under autoscaling might be showing as available to kube scheduler before they are actually ready and requests going to that new pod before it can run requests might be giving 502. I have **increased the minimum count of pods to 10 for that microservice** but still the same issue repeats.

we are using nginx ingress controller. I tried to check ingress logs, I can see the 502 errors but nothing helpful to debug there also. as you can see

```
24.171.57.159 - - [08/Dec/2022:21:40:27 +0000] "POST /lender/api/v1/dealer/getUserDetailsById HTTP/2.0" 502 150 "https://portal.leverauto.com/Admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Safari/605.1.15" 402 51.967 [default-lever-lender-service-5009] [] 10.240.0.155:5009 0 51.935 502 b8a41fdba7930aea0a9b22780024bd65
```

I am also attaching full file of ingress logs here, if it is helpful to see what might be the issue [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eqI5WEPYa3M7FuQq6lG9QpGyqVwbHEVg/view?usp=share_link)

Also here is my both ingress files, we are using 2 ingress as backend needs rewrite annotation while frontend doesn't need that rewrite hence.

ingress-r.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-r
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - portal.leverauto.com
    secretName: lever-ssl
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: lever-webapp-service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: portal.leverauto.com
    http: &http_rules
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-webapp-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

ingress-srv.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - portal.leverauto.com
    secretName: lever-ssl
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: lever-webapp-service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: portal.leverauto.com
    http: &http_rules
      paths:
      - path: /auth(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-authentication-service
            port:
              number: 5000
      - path: /auction(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-auction-service
            port:
              number: 5010 
      - path: /audit(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-audits-service
            port:
              number: 5005                      
      - path: /inventory(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-inventory-service
            port:
              number: 5006         
      - path: /lender(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-lender-service
            port:
              number: 5009 
      - path: /payment(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-payments-service
            port:
              number: 5002
      - path: /report(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-reports-service
            port:
              number: 5003 
      - path: /sopraData(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-sopra-datapull-service
            port:
              number: 5011
      - path: /sopra(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-sopra-service
            port:
              number: 5008
      - path: /vehicle(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-vehicle-service
            port:
              number: 5001
      - path: /workflow(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: lever-workflow-service
            port:
              number: 5004
```

This is a critical Production issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, we are also facing this. Any updates on how it was resolved? Will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

setting this may help

```
server.keepAliveTimeout = 61 * 1000;
server.headersTimeout = 65 * 1000; // This should be bigger than `keepAliveTimeout + your server's expected response time`
```

see https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2019/04/25/keep-alive-timeout/