# Backstage application working intermittently

Tags: azure-aks, backstage

We have deployed backstage application on AKS cluster and we used nginx ingress controller for our application, but the application is not stable, it works for 2 minutes, and goes down for long time (working intermittently). We are not able to find the root cause, we can't even see any error in pod logs. The same application is working in another environment without any issues.

We see http 502 error intermittently.

We tried to redeploy nginx as well as the backstage application, but it did not help.

Comment: Got some code to show for someone to review, otherwise its just a guessing game in here.

Comment: ensure that the necessary firewall rules are in place to allow traffic to the Ingress Controller and make sure to check mark 
[below](https://i.imgur.com/fgWyYyT.png) necessary firewall rules are in place for your AKS cluster, allowing external traffic to reach your Nginx Ingress Controller. If the issue persists you need to check logs 

    kubectl logs -n <namespace> -l app=nginx-ingress
Inspect the resource usage (CPU, memory) of the Backstage pods to see if there's resource exhaustion which could cause the pod to become unresponsive.

Comment: Refer to these -

[Official Backstage guide](https://backstage.io/docs/deployment/k8s/)

[Backstage on K8s example](https://john-tucker.medium.com/backstage-and-kubernetes-by-example-3b49725e8acb)

[Similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739796/getting-502-bad-gateway-errors-intermittently-in-azure-kubernetesaks?rq=2)

Answer (score 0):

Intermittent issues like the one you're experiencing with your Backstage application on an AKS cluster can be challenging to diagnose,especially when there are no clear error messages in the pod logs.This is more of a troubleshooting question. Howevever, the HTTP 502 error suggests a problem with the gateway or proxy (in this case, Nginx), which is failing to get a valid response from your Backstage application.

Below is an example to deploy backstage on AKS using [helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/backstage/backstage)

```
helm install backstage backstage/backstage -n backstage
```

[image]

If you want to take the manual deployment route, you can do that as well.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backstage
  namespace: backstage
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backstage
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backstage
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backstage
          image: backstage:<backstageversion>
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 7007
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: postgres-secrets
            - secretRef:
                name: backstage-secrets
```

For production deployments, the `image` reference will usually be a full URL to a repository on the container registry for example: arkocr.azurecr.io/backstage
Now if you want to check it on localhost:

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace=backstage svc/backstage 80:80  
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:80 ->  7007
```

But for this example sake I will be using helm

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

[image]

then create an Ingress resource that will route traffic to your Backstage service. Save it with `kubectl apply -f yourfilename`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backstage-ingress
  namespace: backstage
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backstage
            port:
              number: 80
```

After the Nginx Ingress Controller is successfully installed, it will be assigned an external IP, your pods backstage pods are up and you can access it on your browser
`kubectl get svc -n backstage`
[image]
[image]

Now coming to your intermittent issue, if you are running this on AKS, ensure that the necessary firewall rules are in place to allow traffic to the Ingress Controller and make sure to check mark below
[image]

By following these steps, you should be able to ensure that the necessary firewall rules are in place for your AKS cluster, allowing external traffic to reach your Nginx Ingress Controller. If the issue persists you need to check logs

```
kubectl logs -n <namespace> -l app=nginx-ingress
```

Inspect the resource usage (CPU, memory) of the Backstage pods to see if there's resource exhaustion which could cause the pod to become unresponsive.

Reference Document:

[Official Backstage guide](https://backstage.io/docs/deployment/k8s/)

[Backstage on K8s example](https://john-tucker.medium.com/backstage-and-kubernetes-by-example-3b49725e8acb)

[Similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739796/getting-502-bad-gateway-errors-intermittently-in-azure-kubernetesaks?rq=2)

Comment: we had created two aks clusters within same VNET, second cluster was just for POC we didn't installed backstage on that cluster , issue resolved after deleting second cluster, it might be going on that cluster (IP conflict) but it did not getting any service on that ip

Comment: It appears that the presence of the second AKS cluster in the same VNET was causing a networking conflict that affected your Backstage application. This could have been due to IP conflicts or misrouting of traffic. Deleting the POC cluster resolved the issue, indicating that the clusters were interfering with each other's network space. To prevent such issues, ensure each AKS cluster within the same VNET has unique network configurations and IP ranges.